# Volume of truncated pyramid triangle base

Tags: geometry

Find the volume of a truncated pyramid with height 10. One base has sides 27, 29, and 52. The truncation base has a base perimeter of 72.

I understand this is a pyramid minus a pyramid question but as I am only given the height of the chunk I don't understand how to get the full pyramid height?

Comment: What is the perimeter of the base whose sides are known? 
Compare the two diameters .... can this help?

Answer (score 0):

Let $a, b$ & $c$ be the sides of truncation triangular base parallel to the sides $27, 29$ & $52$ respectively. then perimeter of truncation base is $a+b+c=72$.

Let $h$ be the vertical height of part which is removed from original pyramid of height $(h+10)$. Then using the properties of similar triangles for removed part of height $h$ & the original pyramid (before truncation) of height $h+10$,
$$\frac{h}{h+10}=\frac{a}{27}=\frac{b}{29}=\frac{c}{52}=\frac{a+b+c}{27+29+52}=\frac{72}{108}=\frac23$$
Above relation gives, $$h=20, a=18, b=\frac{58}{3}, c=\frac{104}{3}$$
Now, the area of triangular base $A_b$ with sides, $27, 29, 52$ is given by Heron's formula 
$$A_b=\sqrt{54(54-27)(54-29)(54-52)}=270$$
Similarly, the area of truncation triangular base $A_t$ with sides, $a=18, b=58/3, c=104/3$ is given by Heron's formula 
$$A_t=\sqrt{36\left(36-18\right)\left(36-\frac{58}{3}\right)\left(36-\frac{104}{3}\right)}=120$$
Now, the volume of truncated pyramid will be equal to the difference of volume of original pyramid with height $h+10=30$ and that of the removed part (in form of a similar pyramid) of height $h=20$ 
$$=\frac{1}{3}\times A_b\times (h+10)-\frac{1}{3}\times A_t\times (h)$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}\times 270\times 30-\frac{1}{3}\times 120\times 20$$
$$=1900\ \mathrm{unit^3}$$